# Node js token Role-based access control.

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, rbac

I've been looking around but couldn't really find anything, but does anyone one know a way or know a npm package that can get you to send a token to someone that will grant them Role-based access control to your website such as Administrator etc?

Answer (score 0):

You give the user a token on login. Hence, you know what roles he has. You can just add those roles in the payload of the token.

Then while verifying the token in the API request you can see if he has a certain required role (for that operation).